# Executing JavaScript Commands in Another Window

Tags: javascript, html, window.open

I have this program that requires me to open an window using the `window.open("https://link_goes_here")` javascript command, and then use more javascript stuff to do `reload()` and to open some chrome:// links. I lost the origional code that I used for this (accidentally wiped the SSD of my computer :P), but heres the mockup of it:

```
<script>
function hi() {
//This opens the window V
    window.open("https://link_goes_here.com")
//This is going to happen to the window V
window.open("chrome://this_is_a_chrome_link")
reload()
window.open("chrome://this_is_another_chrome_link")
}
</script>

<button onclick="hi()">Click Me!</button>
```

(its in HTML)

I have no idea what do do, and I can't find anything online. The general gist of this is how to  get the javascript to run in the window, like the `reload()` and changing the link to the window to a chrome tab? Thanks in advance :).
(also I am very stupid so please elaborate when you are answering. Thanks!)

Comment: No, you cannot do that, in particular not for `chrome://` urls, for security reasons.

Comment: What is this program doing? What is your [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)?

Comment: A friend told me that some Chrome links do cool things, and I kinda want to prank one of my other friends. The Chrome links are a link for the Chrome security risk demo page. Isn't a top priority :P.

Comment: A link should never *do* things, it should lead to a page where the user can do things. Especially for security settings it's obvious that it must the user who changes them, not an arbitrary web page. You can open the settings page but nothing more.

Comment: Makes sense now that you mention it.